# Converting a CGRect from a view to superview not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uistackview

I am creating a board game that is based on the chess board.
In order to create the board game, I did this:

1. Imagine a chess board divided in 8 columns of white and block squares.
2. I created a XIB to represent the even columns. That XIB is a vertical `UIStackView` of white and black squares.
3. I created a second XIB to represent the odd columns. That XIB is a vertical `UIStackView` of black and white squares.column.
4. on the storyboard I create the board view and add these columns, even, odd, even, odd, etc., to represent the full board with 8 columns each with 8 squares. So I have this:

> ```
> `BOARD VIEW`
>    |
>    ├─ EVEN COLUMN VERTICAL UISTACKVIEW with 8 vertical squares
>    ├─ ODD COLUMN VERTICAL UISTACKVIEW with 8 vertical squares
>    ├─ EVEN COLUMN VERTICAL UISTACKVIEW with 8 vertical squares
>    ├─ ODD COLUMN VERTICAL UISTACKVIEW with 8 vertical squares
>    ├─ EVEN COLUMN VERTICAL UISTACKVIEW with 8 vertical squares
>    ├─ ODD COLUMN VERTICAL UISTACKVIEW with 8 vertical squares
>    ├─ EVEN COLUMN VERTICAL UISTACKVIEW with 8 vertical squares
>    └─ ODD COLUMN VERTICAL UISTACKVIEW with 8 vertical squares
> ```

Now I want to get the frame of a square that is inside one of these columns and convert that to the frame reference of the board.

I do this on `MyBoardView.m`:

```
CGRect convertedFrame = [self convertRect:[aSquare frame] toView:self];
```

`self` is the board view, `aSquare` is one square that is inside a stack that is inside `self`. This conversion has no effect. `convertedFrame` is equal to `[aSquare frame]`.

I think that the problem is that `UIStackView` is not a view. How do I solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convertRect:toView: converts a rect that is in the receiver's coordinate system to a different coordinate system.  But [aSquare frame] is not in `MyBoardView` coordinate system it is in it's superview's coordinate system (ie one of the view that are in the middle).  Instead try

```
CGRect convertedFrame = [self convertRect:[aSquare bound] fromView:aSquare];
```

Here `MyBoardView` is being ask to convert a Rect that is in `aSquare`'s coordinate system to a rect in its own coordinate system. If they share any common superview it will be able to do it.

This, by the way, would be identical to:

```
CGRect convertedFrame = [aSquare convertRect:[aSquare bound] toView:self];
```

the difference between fromView and toView is only who is the receiver and who is the parameter.  (Having the same caller and parameter is a big red flag when using convertRect methods).